# How can I iterate though each child node in an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML File and i would like to iterate though each child node gathering information.

Here is my C# code it only picks up one node, the FieldData i would like to use a foreach on its child nodes.

```
public void LoadXML() {
    if (File.Exists("Data.xml")) {
        //Reading XML
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("Data.xml");

        //Think something needs to reference Child nodes, so i may Foreach though them

        XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//FieldData"); 
        TagContents[] ArrayNode;

        foreach(XmlNode node in dataNodes) {
            int Count = 0;
            //int Max = node.ChildNodes.Count;
            ArrayNode = new TagContents[Max];

            ArrayNode[Count].TagName = node.Name;
            ArrayNode[Count].TagValue = node.SelectSingleNode(ArrayNode[Count].TagName).InnerText;
            Count = Count + 1;        
        }
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not find file Data.xml");
    }
}
```

---

My XML Looks Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FieldData>
  <property_details_branch IncludeInPDFExport="Yes" Mod="20010101010101"/>
  <property_details_inspection_date IncludeInPDFExport="Yes" Mod="20120726200230">20120727220230+0200</property_details_inspection_date>
  <property_details_type_of_ownership IncludeInPDFExport="Yes" Mod="20120726134107">Freehold</property_details_type_of_ownership>
</FieldData>
```

Comment: I'd just like to note that in your `foreach` loop you set `Count` to zero, do stuff, increment it and set in back to zero.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're iterating the FieldData nodes and you have only one. To iterate its child nodes write:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
{
     foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
     {
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) ?

Comment: I advise you to look in the other answers about XDocument. You should use it instead of XmlDocument.

Comment: Be aware, though, that if someone decides to add comments or text nodes under <FieldData>, your loop will pick those up too.

Comment: I think, this code will iterate till level 2 only. It will not give the values if their are sub childs at level 2.

Answer (score 8):

I generally prefer [Linq-To-Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for this kind of thing:

```
  var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
  foreach (var child in doc.Element("FieldData").Elements())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(child.Name);
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you use recursion:

```
    public void findAllNodes(XmlNode node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
        foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes)
            findAllNodes(n);
    }
```

Where do you place the payload depends on what kind of search you want to use (e.g. breadth-first search, depth-first search, etc; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Data.xml");
    TagContents[] ArrayNode = doc.Root
                                .Elements()
                                .Select(el =>
                                    new TagContents()
                                    {
                                        TagName = el.Name.ToString(),
                                        TagValue = el.Value
                                    })
                                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just touching on @Waynes answer, which worked well. I used the below code to push further into the child nodes in my xml

```
foreach (var child in doc.Element("rootnodename").Element("nextchildnode").Elements()) 

{

 //do work here, probs async download xml content to file on local disc

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void ValidateXml(string[] Arrays)
    {                                         
        foreach (var item in Arrays)
        {
            Xdoc.Load(item);                              
            XmlNodeList xnList = Xdoc.SelectNodes("FirstParentNode");
            if (xnList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    XmlNodeList anode = xn.SelectNodes("SecondParentNode");
                    if (anode.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode bnode in anode)
                        {                               
                            string InnerNodeOne = bnode["InnerNode1"].InnerText;
                            string InnerNodeTwo = bnode["InnerNode1"].InnerText;

                        }                           
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ErrorLog("Parent Node DoesNot Exists");                                                 
                    }
                }                  
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorLog("Parent Node DoesNot Exists");
            }

        }
       //then insert or update these values in database here
    }
```

Comment: what is there are more levels of parent nodes? I think your code will break at that time.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through each and every child node, sub-child node and so on, We have to use `Recursion`. In case someone have the same requirement as I had, I achieved this something like below -

```
public string ReadAllNodes(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode subNode in node)
        {
            //Recursion
            ReadAllNodes(subNode);
        }
    }
    else //Get the node value.
    {
        finalText = finalText + node.InnerText + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
    return finalText;
}
```