# Convert from XML to CSV

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have been searching for the solution to convert XML into CSV, but I cannot find one which matches my case as XML structure is different

XML structure looks like

```
<VWSRecipeFile>
    <EX_Extrusion User="ABC" Version="1.0" Description="" LastChange="41914.7876341204">
        <Values>
            <C22O01_A_TempFZ1_Set Item="A_TempFZ1_Set" Type="4" Hex="42700000" Value="60"/>
            <C13O02_A_TempHZ2_Set Item="A_TempHZ2_Set" Type="4" Hex="43430000" Value="195"/>
            <C13O03_A_TempHZ3_Set Item="A_TempHZ3_Set" Type="4" Hex="43430000" Value="195"/>
        </Values>
    </EX_Extrusion>
</VWSRecipeFile>
```

Expected CSV Format

A_TempFZ1_Set,A_TempHZ2_Set,A_TempHZ3_Set

60,195,195

i can achieve the new expected csv format, but don't know if it is the best way to do it, any suggestion is appreciated

'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/VWSRecipeFile">

      <xsl:for-each select="EX_Extrusion/Values/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Item,',')" />
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

      <xsl:for-each select="EX_Extrusion/Values/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Value,',')" />
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'
```

Thanks

Comment: What tool are you using? What's your intended CSV format? Is this a one off conversion or you have to do this regularly?

Comment: I am using C# and i will have to do it regularly.
Intention is to be able to read all the elements of "Values" tag
Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the expected CSV output from the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is to use XSLT, the language designed to work with XML. You surely can parse the XML with C# but I like XSLT cause it's cleaner.

You define an external XSLT file, then call it within C# to do the transform.

**Edit:** added new columns based on new requirements.

File C:\XmlToCSV.xslt (`&#xA;` is the newline character)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/VWSRecipeFile">
      <xsl:variable name="User" select="EX_Extrusion/@User"/>
      <xsl:variable name="Version" select="EX_Extrusion/@Version"/>
      <xsl:variable name="Description" select="EX_Extrusion/@Description"/>
      <xsl:variable name="LastChange" select="EX_Extrusion/@LastChange"/>

      <xsl:text>Item,Type,Hex,Value,User,Version,Description,LastChange&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="EX_Extrusion/Values/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Item,',',@Type,',',@Hex,',',@Value,',',$User,',',$Version,',',$Description,',',$LastChange,'&#xA;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apply the transform with `XslCompiledTransform`:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("C:\\XmlToCSV.xslt");
xslt.Transform("InputFile.xml", "OutputFile.csv");
```

Adjust it based on your needs.

Comment: Thank you Zoff, this is exactly what i was looking for.
I haven't worked on Xslt ever. Would it be possible to also concat the values of "EX_Extrusion" attributes - User="ABC" Version="1.0" Description="" LastChange="41914.7876341204" like 
<xsl:value-of select="concat(@Item,',',@Type,',',@Hex,',',@Value,@User,@Version,@Description,@LastChange,'&#xA;')"/>

Thank you

Comment: I can't write you an XSLT unless I know what you are looking for. Please edit the question to include your expected CSV output.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea would be to [iterate though values nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759426/how-can-i-iterate-though-each-child-node-in-an-xml-file) and select the attributes you want for each node and keep writing them to a file with comma separator. Simply name the file as .csv. If you want something ready made, check [this](http://xmltocsv.codeplex.com/) out.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is one way to do it. Alternatively you can use, [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library available to parse xml, produce CSV the way you want it.

```
string xml = @"<VWSRecipeFile>
    <EX_Extrusion User=""ABC"" Version=""1.0"" Description="""" LastChange=""41914.7876341204"">
        <Values>
            <C22O01_A_TempFZ1_Set Item=""A_TempFZ1_Set"" Type=""4"" Hex=""42700000"" Value=""60""/>
            <C13O02_A_TempHZ2_Set Item=""A_TempHZ2_Set"" Type=""4"" Hex=""43430000"" Value=""195""/>
            <C13O03_A_TempHZ3_Set Item=""A_TempHZ3_Set"" Type=""4"" Hex=""43430000"" Value=""196""/>
        </Values>
    </EX_Extrusion>
</VWSRecipeFile>";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xml).WithXPath("/Values/*"))
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(sb)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        )
        w.Write(p.ToDictionary(r => r.Item, r => r.Value).ToDynamic());
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output:

```
A_TempFZ1_Set,A_TempHZ2_Set,A_TempHZ3_Set
60,195,196
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.