# How do I modify a XML Node?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to modify the Node my XML File look like this.

```
<Tasks>
   <Task>
      <Title>Title of the Task</Title>
      <Description>Description of the Task</Description>
      <Done>false</Done>
   </Task>

   <Task>
      <Title>Title of anotherTask</Title>
      <Description>Description of anotherTask</Description>
      <Done>true</Done>
   </Task>
 </Tasks>
```

I could adress the Node like this:

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Tasks/Task/Description").InnerText = "My Description";
```

However I have mulitple Tasks. How do I indicate which is which? I want to change the State of the Task "Done" from false to true.

Comment: have you tried doing a google search I am pretty sure there are plenty of working examples of this already on `SO`

Comment: Put a filter on your xpath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : Modify a xml node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616163/c-sharp-modify-a-xml-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through each resulting node from something like this:

```
foreach( XmlNode xn in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Tasks"))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Doing what you need to do on each node. More info on SelectNodes here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you have control over the design of the XML, perhaps you should consider adding an ID to your task. An ID will allow you to make changes to an specific Task node instead of iterating through them or looking up by Task.Title.

You may also look at these articles:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx
- [How can I iterate though each child node in an XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759426/how-can-i-iterate-though-each-child-node-in-an-xml-file)

Having said all this, I feel your question is missing some more information on what is the criteria on when to do that something correctly. Could you expand some more? You will get better answers that way.

Comment: Hey, yea I have control over the XML File. How would you implement the ID? I want to create a simple To-Do List. It's a CheckBox andin the CheckedChange Event I want to move  the Task from the Tab "Working on" (Done=false) to "Done" (Done=true). This is working however I wanted to change the Value in the XML File.. which I didn't know how. I will do some researches about the ID which seems to be a good way. :)

Comment: In my opinion it could be as simple as: <Task><ID>[some unique identifier]</ID>...</Task>

Comment: Once you are done with your changes, don't forget to save (XmlDocument.Save). See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: In case you need help with the XPath, it will look something like this: "/Tasks/Task[ID=35.00]". See: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp